# Delete Entire Column if column only consists of zeros and blank values

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2010

I was wondering if someone could help me with this excel VBA challenge i faced,

I am trying to delete a column if a column has only 0 and blank values, the format looks like the below picture:

As i have highlighted the two columns has only zero and blank values and those 2 columns should be deleted.

[Excel Column Format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JGbP3.png)

I have tried this code but unfortunately it deletes all the columns:

```
Sub dynamicRange()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Dim startCell As Range, lastRow As Long, lastCol  As Long, ws As Worksheet

        Set ws = ActiveSheet
        Set startCell = Range("E9")

            lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
            lastCol = ws.Cells(startCell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

            ws.Range(startCell, ws.Cells(lastRow, lastCol)).Select

                Set a = Selection

                    For Each cell In a
                        If cell.Value = "Total" Or cell.Value = "Tag" Or cell.Value = "Delivery Fee" Or cell.Value = "CC/Cash" Or cell.Value = "Postcode" Then
                                cell.EntireColumn.Delete
                        End If
                    Next cell

                    For Each cell In a
                        If cell.Value = 0 Or cell.Value = "" Then
                                cell.EntireColumn.Delete
                        End If
                    Next cell

    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Looking forward for a solution, Thank you.

Comment: your wording doesn't match yor code: what does that `If cell.Value = "Total" Or cell.Value = "Tag" Or cell.Value = "Delivery Fee" Or cell.Value = "CC/Cash" Or cell.Value = "Postcode" Then` code line has to do with the former?

Answer (score 1):

you can use count number of populated cells in range

```
WorksheetFunction.CountA(range)
```

This is sample code

```
sub test()
   dim lasCol as integer
   lastCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

   for i = lastCol to 1 Step - 1
      if worksheetfunction.countA(Columns(i)) = 0 then
         Columns(i).delete
      end if 
   next i

end sub
```

Of course you can change Column to Range to check it content data or not that fit your file. eg

```
if worksheetfunction.countA(range("A2:A10, A15:A20")) = 0 then
```

Or

```
if worksheetfunction.countA(range(cells(2,i), cells(10,i))) + worksheetfunction.countA(range(cells(15,i), cells(20,i)))= 0 then
```

Comment: It won't work. You have to go from lastCol to 1. Think about it, e.g. i is 2 and you delete  the 2nd column. Now the 3rd column is the 2nd column but i is already 3, so you're not checking the previous 3rd column.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. As you said I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete columns without value you can use Excel's own SUM() function with simple code as shown below.

```
Sub DynamicRange()

    Dim startCell As Range
    Dim SumRng As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol  As Long
    Dim C As Long

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        Set startCell = .Range("E9")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
        lastCol = .Cells(startCell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        For C = lastCol To startCell.Column Step -1
            Set SumRng = .Range(.Cells(startCell.Row, C), .Cells(lastRow, C))
            If Application.Sum(SumRng) = 0 Then .Columns(C).Delete
        Next C
    End With

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

End Sub
```

I'm not sure I understand the significance of your `startCell` at E9 correctly. Your code doesn't appear to match with the picture of your worksheet in that respect. My code ignores values which are above row 9 but that would be very easy to modify. Just let me know. The point is that using the SUM() function makes the code run much faster than having to examine every cell.

Answer (score 0):

### Delete Zero-Blank Columns

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub DeleteEmptyColumns()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Dim rng As Range, URng As Range, startCell As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, lastCol As Long, ws As Worksheet
    Dim j As Long   ' Column Counter
    Dim i As Long   ' Row Counter

    On Error GoTo ProgramError

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set startCell = ws.Range("E9")

    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, startCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
    lastCol = ws.Cells(startCell.Row, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For j = startCell.Column To lastCol
        For i = startCell.Row To lastRow
            Set rng = ws.Cells(i, j)
            If rng.Value <> 0 And rng.Value <> "" Then Exit For
        Next
        If i > lastRow Then Set rng = ws.Cells(1, j): GoSub UnionRange
    Next

'    ' While developing such a code, use Hidden instead of Delete.
'    If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True

    If Not URng Is Nothing Then URng.EntireColumn.Delete

    MsgBox "Operation finished successfully."

SafeExit:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub

UnionRange:
    If Not URng Is Nothing Then
        Set URng = Union(URng, rng)
    Else
        Set URng = rng
    End If
    Return

ProgramError:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred."
    On Error GoTo 0
    GoTo SafeExit

End Sub
```